# Why is a banner not shown for my local notification in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, background, notifications

My iOS 7 app is generating local notifications in a method called within an NSOperationQueue block.  The notifications are appearing in the Notification Center, but they are not showing a banner at the top of the screen.  The notifications are being generated while the app is in the background.

I've tried everything I can think of, and done considerable Google searching, but I still can't get the banners to display.

Here is the code that builds and schedules the notification:

```
    // In the most recent case, I have verified that 
    // alertText = Why not work? and alertAction = View

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
    localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;

    localNotification.alertLaunchImage = launchImage;

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber++;

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(scheduleNotification:) 
    withObject:localNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)scheduleNotification: (id)notification
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = (UILocalNotification *)notification;

    // Schedule it with the app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

I have checked the notification settings for my app, and they are:

Alert Style: Banners
Badge App Icon: On
Sounds: Off
Show in Notification Center: On
Include: 5 Recent Items
Show on Lock Screen: On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was actually in a different part of my code.  I was generating the notification in a background thread, and the thread was canceled before the notification went out.

Comment: How can it not canceled before the local notification send out?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running you can't have this banners (unless you create your own).

A solution could be:

When the app is running, `Notification` are handle by

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Then you can use this project (that I use and which is really good) :  [TSMessages](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages) to create something similar as your banner.

Hope that will help...